# Open redirection (DOM-based) on ASP.NET 4.7 Web Forms

Tags: xss, asp.net, burp-suite

A scan with Burp Suite has reported a possible vulnerability on all the pages of my application, which is based on ASP.NET 4.7 WebForms.

the issue is: The application may be vulnerable to DOM-based open redirection. Data is read from document.location.pathname and passed to the 'open()' function of an XMLHttpRequest object.

I think it is related to a piece of JS code of the .NET framework in **WebResource.axd**:

```
function WebForm_PostBackOptions(eventTarget, eventArgument, validation, validationGroup, actionUrl, trackFocus, clientSubmit) {
this.eventTarget = eventTarget;
this.eventArgument = eventArg
...[SNIP]...
backIndex;
if (setRequestHeaderMethodExists) {
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = WebForm_CallbackComplete;
    callback.xmlRequest = xmlRequest;
    // e.g. http:
    var action = theForm.action || document.location.pathname, fragmentIndex = action.indexOf('#');
    if (fragmentIndex !== -1) {
        action = action.substr(0, fragmentIndex);
    }
    if (!__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        var domain = "";
        var path = action;
        var query = "";
        var queryIndex = action.indexOf('?');
        if (queryIndex !== -1) {
            query = action.substr(queryIndex);
            path = action.substr(0, queryIndex);
        }
        if (path.indexOf("%") === -1) {
            // domain may or may not be present (e.g. action of "foo.aspx" vs "ht
            ...[SNIP]...
        else {
            domain = path.substr(0, slashAfterDomain);
            path = path.substr(slashAfterDomain);
        }
    }
    action = domain + encodeURI(path) + query;
    }
}
xmlRequest.open("POST", action, true);
xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
xmlRequest.send(postData);
return;
}
```

What Burp thinks it's a vulnerability is given by the following lines:

1. var action = theForm.action || document.location.pathname,fragmentIndex = action.indexOf('#');
2. action = action.substr(0, fragmentIndex);
3. query = action.substr(queryIndex); action = domain + encodeURI(path) + query;
4. xmlRequest.open("POST", action, true);

But analyzing the code I think it's a false positive, as the domain cannot be re-written by any users input or related variables.
What do you think?